# Plotting multiple time durations in Excel

Tags: excel, time, graph, charts, plot

I want to plot a graph in excel which has x-axis values as times(just of one day, this will be plotted everyday) and y-axis values as different applications. Suppose an application A runs jobs from 1:00 pm to 2:00 pm and then from 4:00 pm to 6:00 pm. Is there a way I can plot these time durations for each application?

I am visualizing a graph where an application has a colored bar next to it for the time period 1pm to 2pm and then it is blank until 4pm where another colored bar appears till 6pm.

Is this possible? I have the start and end times of jobs for each application. Differentiating between jobs is not important. I just need to know when the application is running and when it is idle.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Thanks! I'll go through the peltier documents, should be able to understand how the values are structured

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little example:

[image: SO24459314 example]

The data is a label in ColumnA (for the y-axis) and 'readings' (here in B1:G1). The 'readings' are the length of the static intervals (in hours). `0` because the day has changed, then `13` because nothing happens until 1p.m., `1` because busy 1-2 p.m. - and so on.

If charted with Insert Stacked Bar the default will be to colour fill each range (interval) with a different colour. For the image, the colour for alternate 'series' has been set to match the background and one of the remaining set to match the other.

I admit changing the fill manually could get tedious if required daily for many apps but there is always VBA! And with a small fudge you may be able to 'recycle' (ie use the chart as a template and just overwrite "yesterday's" data.